# Resource Bundle 0.2* installation failed in sylius?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2, sylius

**I want to install resource bundle in sylius i used below command using cmd**

```
composer require sylius/resource-bundle:0.2.*
```

**when i ran above command i get below error**

```
composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - sylius/taxation-bundle 0.1.x-dev requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.1.* -> satisfiable by sylius/resour
ce-bundle[v0.1.0].
    - sylius/taxation-bundle 0.1.x-dev requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.1.* -> satisfiable by sylius/resour
ce-bundle[v0.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: sylius/resource-bundle[v0.2.0, v0.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: sylius/resource-bundle[v0.2.0, v0.1.0].
    - Installation request for sylius/resource-bundle 0.2.* -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[v0.2.0]
.
    - Installation request for sylius/taxation-bundle == 0.1.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by sylius/ta
xation-bundle[0.1.x-dev].





Installation failed, reverting composer.json to its original content.
```

*Please share some knowledge..Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to install this bundle? I is already there as it is dependency of all other bundles. You do not need to install it separately. And these bundles use 0.1.* version currently.

Comment: Because i want install **sylius** for that i used command as `php app/console sylius:install` when i ran this command i get error `resource bundle not found` that why i want to install bundle i used reference for install bundle on sylius docs portal i.e [link](http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/installation.html)

Comment: This "resource bundle" can be misleading message, because it's related to missing Intl extension for php, not the SyliusResourceBundle.